# Is there a word meaning "the customer of the customer"?

Tags: business-language

In my work we often talk about our customer's customer. For example, we might sell a widget to Acme, and they then provide widget-related services to Globex Corporation. I've been looking for a generic term for all of the Globexes out there, all of the companies that our direct customers (the Acmes) are selling to.

"Customer of the customer" is the best I've got, but it's pretty awkward. Is there a single word or a more pithy phrase out there?

Comment: There's a phrase *end user*, but that refers to the end of the chain, rather than the next link.

Comment: Our clients' customers? Or our buyers' customers. Or apostrophe-s when referring to Acme alone.

Comment: _End user_ gets to the point. If you want something in between, you'll hafta get an organization chart.

Comment: It's often better to be more specific and concrete. If you're selling timber frames to the building trade then your customer's customer might be a "house buyer".

Comment: Unfortunately the customer's customer often isn't actually the *end user* in this case ... as there is usually at least one more link the chain afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

In my years as a business consultant, the people who paid us were clients and they had customers.

"Our client's customer"